# How can I standardize a list of Excel instructions so that it happens automatically when a file is opened?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not sure what I'm asking entirely, so it's made it difficult to Google. Thank you in advance for the assistance!

I have a spreadsheet that generates each day with different information from the previous day, but all of the same fields.

Instead of making a work instruction that would be a long list of how to modify the spreadsheet to use- I'm looking for a way to automatically be able to apply the changes. Is there a formula or a way to import it to a premade spreadsheet. The type of changes I'm looking for are below:

1. Open file in Excel
2. Delete Row 1
3. Double click the right column boundary of I to fit contents
4. Unwrap text on entire spreadsheet
5. Expand column J to width of at least 20
6. Sort by column E then by column D. Check the box "my data has headers".
7. Make the header for column J "Delivered"

Comment: You can [start with the Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) method

Comment: This is a job for VBA.

Comment: If you are trying Visual Basic (VBA) for the first time, start by using the `Record Macro` ribbon item under Developer (you might have to first go to file>options>customize ribbon, then click Developer), then follow your steps and finally stop the recorder. It will give you base VBA code to start with which you could then modify (your steps do not seem like any modification would be necessary). NOTE; This is only for desktop Excel, online excel uses office scripts (Automate ribbon) which is not the same.